# Get input value with Angular Harness

Tags: angular, unit-testing, protractor, jestjs, karma-jasmine

How can I get the value of Input with Angular Harness?
I tried with this:

```js
  readonly name = this.locatorFor('input');

  async getName(): Promise<string> {
    return (await this.name()).text();
  }
```

And I always getting empty value

```sh
1) ComponentHarness should locate a required element based on CSS selector
  - Expected '' to be 'test1'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the answer,
Although you have input specific functions like `input.clear()`, to get the value you need to use:

```js
  readonly name = this.locatorFor('input');

  async getName(): Promise<string> {
    return (await this.name()).getProperty('value');
  }
```

to learn more about how to use angular harness I recommend checking in github of Angular Material

[Here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/input/testing/input-harness.ts) I found my answer